# play http live stream MP3 in iphone Browser?

Tags: ios, html, safari, video-streaming, vlc

i have successfully transcode RTSP live stream to HTTP live stream (audio MP3) using VLC

[image]

this is the url to my new live stream *if i stream this url in VLC it works fine*

```
    http://174.60.175.62:8080
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u92Az/4/)

**QUESTION**

How can i play this `http` stream in iphone safari

*this is what i have tried and `didn't` work*

```
   <video id="video" src="http://174.60.175.62:8080" autoplay="autoplay">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's MP3 so use HTML5 Audio Element

```
<audio controls="controls" loop="loop">
    <source src="http://westciv.com/podcasts/youmayknowmypoetry.mp3">
</audio>
```

[**Here is all information you needed for HTML5 Audio and Video**](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/)

Comment: @MinaGabriel Not sure about it but try adding the URL in src and check if it works :)